# Map key to toggle between normal mode and insert mode in Vim

Tags: vim

I'd like to use two "controls" as a toggle key to switch between normal mode and insert mode in [Vim](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vim_%28text_editor%29). So I add the following two lines into  my `.vimrc`

```
nmap <C-><C-> i
imap <C-><C-> <ESC>
```

But it doesn't work. What's wrong with the above two lines?

Comment: hm isn't that already build in vim? 'i' enters the edit mode <esc> or ctrl-c exit edit mode?

Comment: Yes, but he wants to be able to press control twice and toggle back and forth.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It seems you are trying to map Ctrl+Space to toggle insert mode.

```
nnoremap <C-space> i
imap <C-space> <Esc>
```

(Came from [this Vim tip](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Toggle_Insert-Normal_Mode_via_ctrl-space) (marked obsolete, but there's a link to a more rich document on avoiding  which includes the tip).)

Remember that this is not guaranteed to work across all terminals and platforms. Some terminals and platforms may eat a given Ctrl+something shortcut, while others don't, so find one that works in your environment.

Comment: That will only work in gvim.  Terminal vim has be told what control character is generated by your ctrl-space.

Answer (score 1):

```
nnoremap <silent><C-space> :startinsert
inoremap <silent><C-space> <C-O>:stopinsert
```

Answer (score 0):

That's definitely not going to work.  You could use an F key instead.

Answer (score 0):

```
nnoremap <C-SPACE> i
inoremap <C-SPACE> <ESC>l
```

works perfectly with GVIM 7.4